# How do I get Batman out of DC Comics Super Heroes Character Encyclopaedia without damaging the book?

Tags: minifigures

I know less than nothing about LEGO, I bought the book because it was on offer and looked cool. 
How do I get Batman out of the book without damaging the book? I can't seem to find any instructions

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You simply open the front cover and you can take out the minifigs from the back. It won't damage the book at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plastic casing on the back of the cover held together with a piece of tape. Cut/break the tape, and then use a fingernail or other thin option to pull apart the two plastic pieces from each other. This opens a small door of sorts, from which you can take out the figure.